# Is it possible to set django-allauth to accept only google login?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, google-signin

I am implementing a web application using Django framework.
In my business I need to let the users have access to the app only by google login.

I also don't need to register the users in my database, it isn't a requirement. I just need that the user will uses his google account to enter the site so I will be able to get his real email to send him back the result of the session. It is a one shot app.

I am using django-allauth but it exposes by default a way to login and register users locally. Is it a way to disable every kind of local registration/login and let the user enter in the app only by google login?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#creating-and-populating-user-instances you'll need to:

- disable signup on a custom `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER`
- enable signup only through social account (google) on a custom `SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER`

In practice:

```py
# settings.py

ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'myapp.adapters.AccountAdapter'
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'myapp.adapters.SocialAccountAdapter'
```

```py
# myapp/adapters.py
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter


class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def is_open_for_signup(self, request):
        return False


class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):

    def is_open_for_signup(self, request, sociallogin):
        return bool(sociallogin)
```